# Имеет ли java метод две задачи?

Tags: java

В java spring есть метод sendRequest , он принимает в параметры String password, потом в методе sendRequest вызывается метод validate которому передается пароль , он его проверяет на запрещённые символы , и возвращает true/false , считается ли что метод sendRequest имеет две задачи , если да , то как это решить. Т.к часто приходится в каком то методе вызывать другой или в каком то классе

Comment: Вопрос достаточно странный.  Как раз то, что логика проверки пароля вынесена в отдельный метод, и позволяет улучшить код метода `sendRequest`, чтобы он был сфокусирован на своей основной задаче -- отправке запроса с корректными данными.  Методы для того и создаются, чтобы их вызывать, и точно так же вы вызовете нужный метод `String`. Другое дело, что валидация какого-то входного аргумента (особенно в спринге) может выполняться при помощи некой аннотации (например, `@Valid`), которая всё равно сведётся к вызову некоторого метода и выбрасыванию исключения, если данные окажутся некорректными.

Comment: В спринге механизмы валидации спрятаны под капотом, о каком методе идёт речь?

Comment: Нет, не имеет. Какая тут под вашему вторая задача у метода sendRequest?